# Tables are not executed after validating and updating schema

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

I have created entities in zend framework 2 using doctrine 2. After that I used this command to validate current schema.

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema
```

I got output like:

```
Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.
```

Then I executed update command,

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --force
```

The output for that is like:

```
Database schema updated successfully! "7" queries were executed
```

But, the problem is, There is no tables created in my database. What's wrong with this?

Comment: are you sure you selected/looking for the right database?

Comment: Yes. That configurations is in config/autoload/doctrine.local.php file.. I didn't touch doctrine.php file in that folder.

Comment: Please paste your doctrine.local config. What is doctrine-module showing when you run validate-schema (after db update)?

Comment: `return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params'      => array(
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'port'     => '3306',
                    'user'     => 'root',
                    'password' => 'root',
                    'dbname'   => 'zf2tutorial',
                )
            )
        )
    )
);`

Answer (score 0):

I used to run *doctrine-module orm:validate-schema* and then *doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create*.
Here is good project to try:
[Fmi-example on github](https://github.com/wingman007/fmi)